# Как подключить беспроводные наушники к линукс манжаро?

Tags: bluetooth, manjaro

Дистр linux Manjaro не видит беспроводные наушники jbl 215tws

P.S
Хочу попробовать полностью перейти на линукс, сейчас стоит как вторая OS единственное что сдерживает так это подключение наушников.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

На скришоте видно, что поиск устройств обнаружил телефон, а не наушники. Дождитесь пока нужное устройство будет найдено, затем установите соединение с ним. У меня отлично работают и наушники, и аудио система. Наушники нужно извлечь, отсоедениться от других устройств, дождаться пока их обнаружит система. Некоторые устройства Manjaro не видит (к сожалению).